# perl hash declaration error

Tags: perl, hash

I am new to perl and can't seem to find why this snippet is giving me a 500 error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );

my ($distance, $weight, $total_gas, $mph, $buffer, $pair, @pairs, $value, $form, $name);
our %FORM = ();

read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs) {
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}
```

Everything I tried on the `%FORM = ();` gives me variable declaration errors.

Comment: my %FORM wouldn't make a difference. Using our just declares the variable to the main namespace.

Comment: When you say "variable declaration errors" what do you mean?  The code is syntactically correct. What's in the log?

Comment: Your title implies (at least to me) that your problem is a Perl syntax error, but I see nothing wrong with your script's syntax (and neither does `perl -cw`).  Consider editing the title, probably to mention the 500 error.

Comment: There's no need to hand-parse CGI parameters like this. The CGI module has been a standard part of the Perl distribution since 1997. Use its "param" function instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you certain that @pairs contains the values you expect (ie that they are name value pairs split with "="? More than likely $name isn't defined and you can't add an undefined key pair to a hash. Why are you using STDIN to read in values from the query string? Try:

```
my $q = CGI->new;
my @keys = $q->param;
my %FORM;
foreach my $name (@keys)
{
    my $value = $q->param($name);
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}
```

or

```
my $q = CGI->new;
my %FORM = $q->Vars;
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: +1 for 'Why are you using STDIN to read in values from the query string?'

Comment: CGI.pm already does all needed translation, so I removed it from your example

Comment: ikegami thanks for the edit. I've been floating between perl and javascript all day which is why I var'd that one. I get those syntax errors all day.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing HTTP header. Try adding to put following line before any print:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

Make sure you have enough permissions for script to run. It'll depend on OS you're using.

Also you'd consider using CGI module as mentioned in [scrappedcola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576196/perl-hash-declaration-error/7576361#7576361)'s answer. This code will work for both POST and GET:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI;

my $form = CGI->Vars;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "name=".$form->{name};
```